# Requesting location updates while Google Maps Navigation is actively running

Tags: android, geolocation

I would like to request location updates from LocationManager using the GPS provider only. I understand that doing this does not immediately return location results.

However, let's assume that the user is currently running the Google Maps Navigation app (i.e., there is an active route) and their GPS signal is strong. Would requesting the GPS location yield a result quickly due to the fact that it is constantly being fixed? Or am I making an invalid assumption?

Furthermore, if I were to call getLastKnownLocation(LocationProvider) while the Navigation app is running, can I assume the last known location will be very close to the current location? How often is the last known location updated when the Navigation app is actively navigating?

Thanks so much!

Comment: "How often is the last known location updated when the Navigation app is actively navigating?" -- that is, at best, a question for the authors of Google Nav. You are welcome to get a job at Google and ask them. What they'll tell you is that they request updates at such-and-so interval today, but whether they get that is based upon environmental factors (e.g., is the car in a parking garage?). They will further explain that they may have need to change their approach in the future. TL;DR: nobody with sense relies upon side-effects of other apps' behavior.

Comment: @CommonsWare I understand that relying on another application is not a good idea. And I also understand that the answer is not simple because of reception and other factors. But I am sure someone can speak to the behavior of these location calls in ideal situations where the user has clear GPS signal and is using their device for navigation.

Answer (score 1):

> Would requesting the GPS location yield a result quickly due to the fact that it is constantly being fixed? Or am I making an invalid assumption?
>
> Furthermore, if I were to call `getLastKnownLocation(LocationProvider)` while the Navigation app is running, can I assume the last known location will be very close to the current location?

If you have a Service that listens for GPS updates, you will have access to the most recent data returned for any application. I recommend using the [`PASSIVE_PROVIDER`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#PASSIVE_PROVIDER) which will receive updates from any provider as they arrive.

Comment: Yes, I will have access to the most recent data returned. I do understand this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I get the GPS fix in my HTC Incredible within 30 secs, regarding your question I tried opening the Navigation app and my application, I dont see any difference if I am running just my application alone.

Would requesting the GPS location yield a result quickly due to the fact that it is constantly being fixed?
The GPS yield a quick fix that depends based on the Satellites.